# cheerio not picking up particular elements

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, jquery-selectors, cheerio

Hi trying to use cheerio to scrape this https://davesgarden.com/guides/pf/finder/index.php?sname=Hibiscus&page=1 , and can access some elements such as the menu items, but not the plant names which i need. Im using this code to try get the plant names

```
const $ = cheerio.load(data);

$('#contAfterAds > div > div.plant-info > div > a').each((_idx, el) => {
            const postTitle = $(el).text()
            postTitles.push(postTitle)
        });
```

but no luck, any suggestions? Ive seen that angular sites cant be scraped, could it be a similar problem?

Answer (score 0):

It's a sibling:

```
$(el).next().text()
```

or possibly:

```
$(el).next().next().text()
```

Comment: https://codepen.io/itsvetobaby/pen/oNweGOg, neither seem to work :/

Comment: You were iterating the a before and the codepen is iterating the h2

Comment: sorry miswrote then pen, its still not working. If you could take a quick look again it would really help me out